# Vagrant: How to configure vagrant to use different Vagrantfiles

Tags: testing, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrantfile

How to use Vagrant for testing e.g. an application running on a Debian, Ubuntu, SuSE etc. VM.

Current project is having one Vagrantfile having configuration inside. To start the Vagrant VM I'm running

```
vagrant up
vagrant provision
```

Now I'm wondering how to do something like

vagrant up suse ... and later vagrant up debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do one of the following:

1. having `git` with different branch and the Vagrantfile will be different depending your branch. Be careful though as your `.vagrant` directory will not match your Vagrantfile, you will need to up and provision each VM and switch the .vagrant directory.
2. you can use [vagrant multi machine](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/) generally you use that to reproduce a multi-tier environment so each VM can be up and running at same time, but you can provision and up each VM independently
3. really use different project folder with each a specific Vagrantfile and a .vagrant directory, each for a specific purpose

Comment: Re 3rd option: Does this mean something like having folders like mycode, vagrant_debian, vagrant_suse .... ?

Comment: yes, each would have their vagrantfile and .vagrant directory